# Getting element from filename using continous split or regex

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, split

I currently have the following string :

```
AAAAA/BBBBB/1565079415419-1564416946615-file-test.dsv
```

But I would like to split it to only get the following result (removing all tree directories + removing timestamp before the file):

```
 1564416946615-file-test.dsv
```

I currently have the following code, but it's not working when the filename itselfs contains a '-' like in the example.

```
getFilename(str){
    return(str.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop().split('-')[1]);
}
```

I don't want to use a loop for performances considerations (I may have lots of files to work with...) So it there an other solution (maybe regex ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try doing a regex replacement with the following pattern:

```
.*\/\d+-\b
```

Replacing the match with empty string should leave you with the result you want.

```js
var filename = "AAAAA/BBBBB/1565079415419-1564416946615-file-test.dsv";
var output = filename.replace(/.*\/\d+-\b/, "");
console.log(output);
```

The pattern works by using `.*/` to first consume everything up, and including, the final path separator.  Then, `\d+-` consumes the timestamp as well as the dash that follows, leaving only the portion you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex and get captured group #1:

```
/[^\/-]+-(.+)$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJ5eB5/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^\/-]+`: Match any character that is not `/` and not `-`
- `-`: Match literal `-`
- `(.+)`: Match 1+ of any characters
- `$`: End

**Code:**

```js
var filename = "AAAAA/BBBBB/1565079415419-1564416946615-file-test.dsv";

var m = filename.match(/[^\/-]+-(.+)$/);

console.log(m[1]);
//=> 1564416946615-file-test.dsv
```